# Accessing IFrame's contentWindow.document gives 'Access is Denied' on IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, cross-domain, access-denied

I did not think it was possible but I hate IE6 twice as much now then this morning.

Please don't bug me about the why but I'll try to explain what we're trying to achieve.
We have 2 apps running, let's say APP1 & APP2, both of them are on the **same domain**. APP1 is including a JavaScript file that is hosted on APP2. This JS file will:

1. Create an IFrame (using document.createElement)
2. Set the source of the IFrame to the root of APP2 (where some HTML is generated);
3. Add a div to the body of APP1
4. Read the contents of the IFrame (so the generated HTML of APP2)
5. set this contents as the innerHTML of the div (3)

So in the end in APP1 we have a header where the contents is generated by APP2 without there being an IFrame on the screen.

The problem lies in step 4; this is working fine for all browsers except for IE6 (could this be the most used sentence in web development?).
I get a JS-error when trying to access contentWindow.document of the iframe: 'Access is denied'. I'm no expert but as I understand this error you would get if both apps were not on the same domain but they are (dev.echnet/APP1 & dev.echnet/APP2).

This is the code I use for above steps (took out stuff that is not executed if not IE6):
(1), (2) & (3):

```
var elIf;
$().ready(function()
{
    elIf = document.createElement('<iframe name="uhframename">');
    elIf.setAttribute('id','idUhFrame');
    document.body.appendChild(elIf);

var uhDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(uhDiv);

elIf.src='dev.echnet/APP1?nocache='+Math.random();
getText();
```

}

(4)

```
function getText() {
        var sContent = "";
        if (elIf.contentWindow.document.body) { // access denied on elIf.contentWindow.document
           ...
        }
}
```

I've googled a lot and tried many possibilities I found (also on SO) but none of them seem to solve this issue.

I also tried setting the domain explicitly on the IFrame by settings its source to this:

> "javascript:(function(){document.open();document.domain=\'dev.echnet\';document.close();})()"

but I'm not exactly sure if this has any effect since I'm setting the source to something else a few steps further. Anyway, since it's the same domain it should not matter?

Hoping for some help or someone to shoot down all IE6 users (a feasible task nowadays) so I can skip this task :-).

Comment: Don't know if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151362

Answer (score 0):

After some working with it for another question on here, I've come up with this solution.

Seems `.document` isn't always necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/sTkVR/4/

I'm using chrome, and it was not working with `.document` but works like a charm with out it

Comment: 3n1gm4: tx, I will try this but above solution is working fine is chrome but not in IE6.

Comment: 3n1gm4: as expected this makes no difference. Tx anyway.