# Internet Explorer: Can't Access IFrame Contents Unless Status Code is 200

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

Because IE doesn't support Asynchronous file uploads, I'm using a work-around that involves posting a form to an iframe. I bind the the onLoad event of the iframe and read its contents when the event is fired. This works well, except when the server returns a status code other than 200, in which case IE8/IE9 throws a "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" error. It seems Microsoft have decided that no one should be allowed to read the contents of an iframe unless the request returns 200 OK.

Googling has turned up nothing, so here I am seeking help. Can anyone else reproduce this odd behavior? Is there anyway around this issue?

The iframe does not violate any cross-site security policies. It's all on the same domain.

Comment: What status code is being returned?

Comment: I've tried 403, 404 and 500. All of them render the iframe contents inaccessible (producing the aformentioned error message). However, any 2xx or 3xx status code seems to be ok. I can probably test more status codes, but I think the pattern is clear - any server or client error as indicated by the status code (4xx, 5xx) causes this error.

Comment: IE8 on Windows XP doesn't seem to have this problem. IE9 in IE8 and IE9 modes on Windows 7 does, as does IE10 on Windows 8.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Do you have a jsfiddle or other demo code showing the problem?

Comment: I think I've worked this one out. It's related to IE's "show friendly error messages" "feature". I tried posting a longer answer with code examples, but stack overflow won't let me for another 4 hours (another cool "feature").

Answer (score 4):

I think I've worked this one out while trying to reproduce the problem on fiddler. Turning off the "Show Friendly HTTP error messages" in IE seems to fix it. The reason I couldn't reproduce it on fiddler is that their 404 pages are over 512 bytes, hence it would show the nginx error regardless.

Basically, the whole issue is that when a page is less than 512 bytes (or 256 in some cases), IE seems to substitute the whole page which has the consequence of blocking access to that page programmatically. Obviously an oversight by Microsoft which still seems to be present in IE10.

It's easy to reproduce. Just place the following in a file (e.g. test.html) under a server than returns a 404 response code under 512 bytes, and ensure your IE is set to show friendly error messages (also make sure "test1.file" doesn't actually exist). Hit the page with IE with the developer console open, and you should see a "access denied" error. How you refresh the page alters the outcome. A CTRL+F5 doesn't seem to exhibit the problem, but a CTRL+R or F5 does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.src = '/test1.file'
document.body.appendChild(iframe )
iframe.contentDocument
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if only I could find where I can submit bug reports for IE10 so we can make our life dealing with this horrific browser just a little better.