# kendo ui upload not working in IE9 at deployment

Tags: upload, internet-explorer-9, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo Ui uploader and WebAPI call to upload a file. **The process im doing goes fine on all browsers even on IE9 locally (localhost), but once i deploy the same code on another domain and i use the kendo upload in IE9 (only in IE9 there's problem), kendo goes directly to the error function and replies with an error message**:

```
' Server response: Error trying to get server response: Error: Access is denied.'
```

Although the webapi method is returning an http response of 201(created), and i set the content type header to "text/plain", plus i'm sending in the body of the http response a json string. I tried so many things (*one of it is configuring X-Frame-Options in IIS*) but couldn't make it work. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: We are also seeing this issue in our code base.  Would appreciate a response!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here [“Access is denied” error on accessing iframe document object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151362/access-is-denied-error-on-accessing-iframe-document-object/151404#151404)

[...]
"So it turns out, that if a response is sent with an error code, IE replaces the content of the iframe with an error message loaded from the disk (res://ieframe.dll/http_500.htm), and that causes the cross-domain access denied error. by Ovesh"