# Access denied error message in IE8

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to access a cross-domain iframe's `contentWindow.document` property.

I'm not actually trying to access the property - I am doing a redirect in JavaScript based on the loaded state of the iframe. MSIE 8+ and Firefox allow this.
`contentWindow.document` is the Webkit based workaround, however checking the status of this property (in Webkit browsers I can check if it is `!== undefined` to determine if the iframe has finished loading.

So, how do I check if referencing this property will cause an access denied error message? I am looking for something simple, since this is for a redirect script that needs to be under 16kb.

Comment: If you control the contents of the iframe as well [this solution is reported to work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151395/1729885).

Comment: Would try/catch work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a real IE8 at hand here, but I think this is a catchable problem, so you could try:

```
try
{
  if(contentWindow.document)
    doSomething();
}
catch(err)
{
  // IE8 did a booboo
}
```

Comment: That's the trouble of it, too - IE9/10 do not present the error if you're working in IE7/8 mode, so I had to install a VM from http://modern.ie/

Comment: Yeah exactly, we have a custom XP+IE8 machine in our vSphere at the office we use for debugging crap like this hehe.