# iframe contentDocument: Access is denied

Tags: javascript, iframe

The following code runs as part of a bookmarklet. It creates an iframe and then tries to access that iframe.

For some sites on IE (tried IE 10) it fails with `Access is denied` for

```
iframeDoc = i.contentDocument || i.contentWindow.document;
```

I've put the call inside a setInterval, which seemed to work for some sites. Apparently they just needed a bit of time.

An example of a site where it does NOT work is [this](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Rum-Raisin-Apple-Pie-236430) site

```
var i=document.createElement('iframe');
i.setAttribute('id', 'my_id');
i.setAttribute('name', 'my_name');
document.body.appendChild(i);


var intervalID = setInterval( function(){
    try{
        var iframeDoc = i.contentDocument || i.contentWindow.document;
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        alert("success!");
    } catch(e){}
}, 10 );
```

I need to access it in order to attach a form to it and then a script that submits the form. I've tried adding them to the iframe before adding the iframe to the body, but that does not work.

Comment: perhaps the solution to this thread can help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151362/access-is-denied-error-on-accessing-iframe-document-object

Comment: Seems to be a different problem. He is actually submitting the form. I can't attach the form to the iframe.

Comment: You hava different domain as host and in the iframe
Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197653/understanding-cross-domain-issue-in-iframes

Comment: Seems too general without any solution, I have already looked at lots of iframe questions and answers. I'm really looking for a specific answer to my question.