# Kendo File Upload with WebApi and IE8/9 Incorrect error message

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui

I have a Web Api to upload a file using KendoUI and it works just fine across all browsers.

However, whenever I tried to validate and generate an exception in IE 8/9 I get this message:

```
' Server response: Error trying to get server response: Error: Access is denied.'
```

While in other browsers like Chrome or Firefox I get the right message.

For example:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "The file is empty")
```

Chrome displays: "The file is empty" and IE 8/9 displays: "Access denied".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and searching I found the answer to my own question:

The answer is here [“Access is denied” error on accessing iframe document object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151362/access-is-denied-error-on-accessing-iframe-document-object/151404#151404)

[...] "So it turns out, that if a response is sent with an error code, IE replaces the content of the iframe with an error message loaded from the disk (res://ieframe.dll/http_500.htm), and that causes the cross-domain access denied error. by Ovesh"